# Global community peer-to-peer search bar

Tags: community, search

I inadvertently deleted the global community peer-to-peer search bar off of my community home page.  Now I have a blank rectangle where I want the search bar.  I can't figure out how to get it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Lighting Template, such as Customer Service (Napili) then it may be caused by one of the following.

If the css from the theme includes

```
.body-search{
display:none;}
```

that will hide the search component. 
[image]

If the entire header region is missing then it could be a setting like these options from either the theme settings or the Theme tab in the Settings, see the images below.

[image: Theme Settings]

[image: Setting Theme tab.]